# Compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)]$ and $\{\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

The problem asked to compute $[\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)]$ and $\{\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)\}$, where the first one is the degree of the extension and the second one is the index of the splitting field. I don't think the first one even exists since $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ is not a finite extension itself. I don't know how to handle the second one.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't this be the other way around? $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. Look at the polynomial $f=X^2-\pi^2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$, but splits in $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.

Comment: @NickyHekster Yes, changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

The polynomial $\;x^2-\pi^2\in\Bbb Q(\pi^2)[x]\;$ vanishes at $\;x=\pi\;$ , so $\;[\Bbb Q(\pi):\Bbb Q(\pi^2)]\le2\;$ ... assuming you meant the extension $\;\Bbb Q(\pi)/\Bbb Q(\pi^2)\;$