# Are $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$ equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

The question was addressed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209876/compute-mathbbq-pi-mathbbq-pi2-and-mathbbq-pi-mathbbq) but I do not know how jo justify that $f(x)=X^2 - \pi^2$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$. That is, $\pi \notin \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\pi\in \mathbb{Q}(\pi^2)$, then there are rational polynomials $P,Q$ such that $\pi Q(\pi^2)=P(\pi^2)$, and thus $\pi$ is a root of $XQ(X^2)-P(X^2)$, a nonzero rational polynomial (since $Q(\pi^2)$ is nonzero), and thus $\pi$ is an algebraic number. We get a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $\pi=P(\pi^2)/Q(\pi^2)$ then $xQ(x^2)-P(x^2)$ is a polynomial whose roots include $\pi$

Answer (score 1):

As $\pi$ is transcendental over $\mathbf Q$, $\;\mathbf Q(\pi)\simeq\mathbf Q(X)$ and  $\;\mathbf Q(\pi^2)\simeq\mathbf Q(X^2)$.

Now $\mathbf Q(X^2)\varsubsetneq\mathbf Q(X)$ for degree reasons, so $\;\mathbf Q(\pi^2)\varsubsetneq\mathbf Q(\pi)$.

Comment: The fact that ${\bf Q}(\pi)\cong {\bf Q}(X)$ and  ${\bf Q}(\pi^2)\cong {\bf Q}(X^2)$ is not enough. After all,  ${\bf Q}(\pi)\cong {\bf Q}(X^2)$ and yet ${\bf Q}(\pi)={\bf Q}(\pi)$.

Comment: Yes, but these isomorphisms are compatible with the canonical injections $\mathbf Q(X^2)\hookrightarrow \mathbf Q(X)$ and  $\mathbf Q(\pi^2)\hookrightarrow \mathbf Q(\pi)$, so that you have a commutative square.

Answer (score 0):

A bit different approach using valuation theory (fleshing out the incomplete argument given by Bernard).

Since $\pi$ is transcendental over $\bf Q$, $\mathbf Q[\pi]$ has a nontrivial $\pi$-adic valuation, i.e. $v_\pi(\sum_k{a_k}\pi^k)=\min\{k\mid a_k\neq 0\}=\max\{k\mid \pi^k\textrm{ divides }\sum_ka_k\pi^k\}$. This can be extended to a valuation on $\mathbf Q(\pi)$ by setting $v_\pi(\frac{f}{g})=v_\pi(f)-v_\pi(g)$.

Now, $v_\pi(\pi)=1$, and it is easy to see that $v_\pi(f)$ is even for any $f\in \mathbf Q(\pi^2)$, so $\pi\notin \mathbf Q(\pi^2)$.